# Elasticsearch Update By Query speed

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have a tiny es index of ~10k documents and I would like to update them universally. Say , I want to change the price for all of the documents. 
Do you have any idea how i could optimize this process? As now it takes ~18s to do the batch update for just 10.000 documents, and it will hold millions in the near future.

**UPDATE**

The specific query is:

```
POST localhost:9200/db_to_es_2/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.price = 100"
    },
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "_type": "product_i18n_v2"
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**
Found out how to set the batch size (scroll_size=...) and it improves the performance when i set the update in large batches.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more detail? How do you update your documents, what command(s) do you use?

Comment: I've updated my post with the update query

Comment: I try to elaborate a bit more for new readers. At the end of the first row you have to set the scroll size, with the first row resulting (in this case) `POST localhost:9200/db_to_es_2/_update_by_query?scroll_size=10000`. For more information please refer to the doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Comment: How large can the scroll size be? I have an index with 43m docs and have to update all. Wondering if I can put a scroll size of 1m

Comment: How large a scroll_size you can have depends on so many things. Number of nodes|servers, storage size, storage speed, CPU speed, memory. Set up monitoring of your server(s), and benchmark. Start small and increase. Tasks can be cancelled. See max index limit index.max_result_window, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html